# Stuck in loop if I start with false answer

Tags: python

```
name = "python"

name_answer = input("What is the name ? ")
while name_answer != name:
    input("No ! Again, What is the name ? ")
else:
    print("Correct answer")
```

If my first answer is "python", I get "correct answer". Untill then, everything is ok.

If I start with a false answer, for instance I input "abcd", the input "No ! Again, what is the name ? " appears. Here also, everything is OK.

But, the issue is I get stuck in the loop "No ! Again, what is the name ? " even if after that, I put the correct answer ("python").

I don't understand, I would like to get out that loop once I put "python" as an input even if I'm starting to input a false answer like "abcd".

Comment: You’re asking for input, but not storing it so it can be compared again in the Ioop condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second input of the user (`input("No ! Again, What is the name ? ")`) wasn't assigned to the `name_answer` variable

```py
name = "python"

name_answer = input("What is the name ? ")
while name_answer != name:
    name_answer = input("No ! Again, What is the name ? ")
else:
    print("Correct answer")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign name_answer to the input:

```
name = "python"

name_answer = input("What is the name ? ")
while name_answer != name:
    name_answer = input("No ! Again, What is the name ? ")
else:
    print("Correct answer")
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the user input in `name_answer`:

```py
name = "python"

name_answer = input("What is the name ? ")
while name_answer != name:
    name_answer = input("No ! Again, What is the name ? ")
else:
    print("Correct answer")
```